# MongoDB with C#.net

Tags: c#, nosql

I am Very new with MongoDB,I m using windows7 32bit,downloaded mongo exe files from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows

And downloaded mongodb.dll also

```
 Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
        mongo.Connect();
```

gives me the error

Failed to connect to server localhost:27017

Is i m missing something,plz let me know

Comment: Did you actually set up and run the server as the guide tells you to - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows#QuickstartWindows-Runandconnecttotheserver - If the server is not running then you won't be able to connect to it

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
```